# How to avoid no match error when using IFS and ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This works:

```
=IFS(
    D8<1,"",
    AND(D8>0,D8<=30),D8*Tariff!$B3+Tariff!$C3
)
```

But this does not

```
=ArrayFormula(
  IFS(
    D8:8<1,"",
    AND(D8:8>0,D8:8<=30),D8:8*Tariff!$B3+Tariff!$C3
  )
)
```

Results in #N/A (Error No match) What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `AND` with multiplication:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFS(
    D8:8<1,"",
    (D8:8>0)*(D8:8<=30),D8:8*Tariff!$B3+Tariff!$C3
  ))
```

The problem is with `AND` because it checks the entire range and returns a single result (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) instead of a range.

Comment: Solution plus rationale ... superb! Thanks.